# Git push to Bonobo 5.2 from vs2015 fails with "Found invalid hex digit in length"

Tags: c#, git, bonobo

Git wizards,

we're just switching from svn to git over here so please don't blame me... 
This is the Problem:

> Set up Bonobo 5.2 on a Windows 2008R2 IIS7 machine
>   Using Bonobo internal auth only
>   Created a new empty repo
>   Created a new solution in vs2015 on client (w10)
>   Commited to local git repo on Client
>   Set up remote repo on Client pointing to Bonobo URL shown in Bonobo Web UI for new repo
>   Tried to push to remote repo (Bonobo)

Error: Found invalid hex Digit in length

Bonobo log states:

w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Error occured and caught in Global.asax - System.FormatException: Ungültige Länge für Base-64-Zeichenarray oder -Zeichenfolge.
   bei System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
   bei System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   bei System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   bei Bonobo.Git.Server.GitAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

add ".git" at the end of the link while specifying remote repository location

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your capitals match in the URL.